# I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 from a DVD

Tags: installation, 12.10

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 from a DVD. (64-bit). I restarted after installation with the DVD in the drive but it went back to the installation menu and started reinstalling. I aborted it and started again. I removed the DVD before installing but now it is hung. Any help is appreciated

philip

Comment: You may have damaged the previous installation.  At what point did you abort?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using boot-able  pen drive , it is the best option.
To make pen drive boot-able use the following command

> sudo dd if="loaction of ubuntu file" of=/dev/sdb.

When I install ubuntu using DVD it gives me problem most of the times.